# Adding Specific Filters For PowerBi Slicers?

Tags: filter, powerbi, slicers

How can I adjust my slicers to only impact a specific value in a column on my table? I'd like to select a Driver from the column and have the slicers only change their FC numbers on the right side of my table.

[image]

Comment: Your question is unclear; Rewrite it or add more details.

Comment: For example, if I select ENGA under driver and want to adjust their "FC Miles"  to 7,238, how I do prevent it from adjusting TTMA and WVAD "FC Miles" as well?